# It is possible to use spotify API to everyone listen a song?

Tags: django, api, spotify, django-channels

I'm plannig to do a chat app with djano and django-channels that will allow me to run te application asyncronous, I want to implement the spotify API for everyone in the room listen to some music, it is possible to do this in an async application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be in theory possible yes. However, it looks like it would be in violation of the [Spotify Developer Policy](https://developer.spotify.com/policy/). (From Section III. Some prohibited applications - point 4):

> Do not create any product or service which includes any non-interactive internet webcasting service. For example, you can’t create an application which plays content from a single source to several simultaneous listeners.

It may well be that it depends, on the finer details of what your application does. From what you've said though, (and having skimmed through their policies) I would definitely suspect such an app would be in violation of their policies.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the Spotify API allows and the implementation requirements to work with the API. Whether your app is synchronous or asynchronous should not really matter for this element, however, async is arguably better practice for the modern web.

You may want to have a look at the Spotify Web Playback SDK for playing tracks in your web browser: [Spotify Web App SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/)